# How to change Crystal Reports connection string using OLE DB in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, connection, oledb

i have a "Connection.vb" where all my Connection string stored and used by the entire program.

i'm new to Crystal Reports.. and i want to changes its connection string based on the connection string i made... im using MS SQL 2008.. SQL Server Native Client 10.0 OLE DB Provider..

and here is my connection string.
"Provider=SQLNCLI10;Server=....\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Blah;Trusted_Connection=yes"

i tried to google it.. but they are using different language, different database, and complex examples...

thanks in advance..

Comment: Are you just asking how you pass a connection string to Crystal Reports from VB?

Answer (score 0):

I just spent some quality time figuring out this exact problem, in VB. I hope this helps.

Replace YourDataContext() with whatever your data context is.  Alternatively, you can get the connection string from the AppConfig as usual.  I am getting mine from the data context because we are migrating databases and keep changing the connection strings.

```
   Private Sub SetCrystalReportsConnection(ByRef report As ReportDocument)

    Dim sqlConnInfo As SqlConnectionStringBuilder = New SqlConnectionStringBuilder(New YourDataContext().Connection.ConnectionString)

    For Each connection As InternalConnectionInfo In report.DataSourceConnections
        If sqlConnInfo.IntegratedSecurity Then
            connection.SetConnection(sqlConnInfo.DataSource, sqlConnInfo.InitialCatalog, True)
        Else
            connection.SetConnection(sqlConnInfo.DataSource, sqlConnInfo.InitialCatalog, sqlConnInfo.UserID, sqlConnInfo.Password)
            connection.IntegratedSecurity = False
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```